# How can I insert this values on this table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let me ask again my last question but with a much better explanation.

These are my tables on my Database:
[image]
This is the content of these tables:

[image]
Every item of the Table1 must be related with every item of the Table2 as you can see on the picture (but I have to do it in a special way) on the Table3

I need to make a query on SqlServer that can do this:

1. List every item of the Table1 that doesnt have every item of the
   Table2 related
2. Insert on the **Table3** the exact values that the Table1 needs to have
       so every value of Table1 is related to Table2

So as you can see in the picture nothing from IdTable2 is going to be added to the IdTable1 = 1 because 1 has all the values of the Table2, but IdTable1 = 2 dont have IdTable2 = 6 and so on.

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried.

Comment: I was trying to do it with a left join but I screw it up and Im to tired from work so I need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
   insert into Table3 (idTable1, idTable2)
     select idTable1, idTable2
       from Table1 cross join Table2
    except
     select idTable1, idTable2 
       from Table3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I was actually doing a cross join right now this was my code
SELECT
c.IdTable1,
v.IdTable2 
FROM Table2 v CROSS JOIN Table1 c

Comment: Good job! However as @Dale Burrell commented on your question, when you show what you have tried so far in your post, it will motivate more volunteers to help you. Anyway glad it helped and good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I'm just learning to code on SQL so I don't know all the possibilities. You are a nice person thank you for helping. I will try to do my best the next time